# How can I use dpkg-query to list only installed version of a package?

Tags: dpkg

I'm using `dpkg-query -f '${Package}\n' -W "linux-image*"` but that doesn't only show what's installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the status as well, then process the output:

```
$ dpkg-query -f '${Package} ${Status}\n' -W "linux-image*"
linux-image unknown ok not-installed
linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic install ok installed
linux-image-4.8.0-51-generic install ok installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic install ok installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-51-generic install ok installed
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 install ok installed
$ dpkg-query -f '${Package} ${Status}\n' -W "linux-image*" | awk '$NF == "installed"{print $1}'
linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic
linux-image-4.8.0-51-generic
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-51-generic
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
```